# Apt can't find melodic (on Ubuntu Focal/20.04)

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I finished an installation of noetic before I realized that the most updated version of the LIDAR driver I was looking to use was only compatible with kinetic or melodic.

So I uninstalled noetic with the following commands:

> sudo apt remove ros-noetic-*

> sudo apt autoremove

then I removed the noetic entry from my bash, and deleted the

> ros-latest.list file

from the

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

directory.

But now when I try to follow the steps to install melodic, I get a

> E: ros-melodic-desktop-full not found error

The only thing different when I follow the steps for noetic would be the fact that I get a 'number of keys unchanged' message, but I'm not sure if that matters since noetic and melodic seem to use the same command for that.

I'm at a loss right now, and I'd appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372235/apt-can%27t-find-melodic-(on-ubuntu-focal/20.04)/) by [hmrbcnt](https://answers.ros.org/users/68369/hmrbcnt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Melodic is not supported on Ubuntu Focal (`20.04`), so that would explain why `apt` can't find it.

You'll have to downgrade to Ubuntu Bionic (`18.04`) to install ROS Melodic.

Or use something like Docker to run a `ros:melodic` image (note that while this is certainly doable, if you're just starting out, this may be a bridge-too-far).

Or you could build the lidar driver you mention (would that be the `velodyne` package? From your #q370291) from source in a Catkin workspace -- there is a good chance that will "just work" (but no guarantees).

---

Edit: for more details (links to the relevant REP 3 *Target Platforms* fi) see #q351321, #q353554, #q371501, #q350668, or #q366244.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hmrbcnt](https://answers.ros.org/users/68369/hmrbcnt/) on 2021-03-07**:
Thank you, unfortunately it never occurred to me that it was an Ubuntu version problem. I've installed a new installation. Thanks!